# Отличие создания объекта при помощи фабричного метода от создания объекта реализующего конкретный интерфейс напрямую

Tags: php, java, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть реализация фабричного метода:

```
    interface Interviewer
    {
        public function askQuestions();
    }

    class Developer implements Interviewer
    {
        public function askQuestions()
        {
            echo 'Спросить о шаблонах проектирования';
        }
    }

    class CommunityExecutive implements Interviewer
    {
        public function askQuestions()
        {
            echo 'Спросить об общественном строительстве';
        }
    }

abstract class HiringManager
{

    // Factory method
    abstract public function makeInterviewer(): Interviewer;

    public function takeInterview()
    {
        $interviewer = $this->makeInterviewer();
        $interviewer->askQuestions();
    }
}

class DevelopmentManager extends HiringManager
{
    public function makeInterviewer(): Interviewer
    {
        return new Developer();
    }
}

class MarketingManager extends HiringManager
{
    public function makeInterviewer(): Interviewer
    {
        return new CommunityExecutive();
    }
}
```

После чего можно использовать:

```
$devManager = new DevelopmentManager();
$devManager->takeInterview(); // Спросить о шаблонах проектирования

$marketingManager = new MarketingManager();
$marketingManager->takeInterview(); // Спросить об общественном строительстве
```

Но я могу и так использовать:

```
$developer = new Developer();
developer.askQuestions() // Спросить о шаблонах проектирования

$сommunityExecutive = new CommunityExecutive();
сommunityExecutive.askQuestions()//Спросить об общественном строительстве
```

т.к и Developer и CommunityExecutive реализуют один интерфейс.
Тогда зачем мне писать эту большую конструкцию с фабричным методом?

Answer (score 1):

Если быть точным, то в вашем примере используется не фабричный метод а `AbstractFactory`. Но не суть.

Есть несколько преимуществ использования данного шаблона по сравнению с созданием объекта напрямую через `new`.

1. Вы имеете больше контроля над созданием объекта и если захотите изменить реализацию, то достаточно будет поменять с `new CommunityExecutive()` на `new Developer()` **в одном месте**
2. Иногда создание объекта довольно трудоемко - требуется передавать куча всяких параметров в конструктор. Тащить все эти параметры каждый раз в то место, где вы хотите создать объект не удобно. Вместо этого создают реализацию абстрактной фабрики в которой уже есть все нужные объекты и передают уже ее в качестве параметра. Например:

```java
void doSmth(String name, int age, String city){
     Person p = new GoodPerson(name, age, city);
}
```

Или так:

```java
void doSmth(GoodPersonFactory factory){
     Person p = factory.create();
}
```

3. Так же иногда возникает потребность в создании не одного а нескольких разных объектов которые логически связанны между собой. И хочется объединить, сгруппировать их создание в одном месте. Например:

```java
interface PizzeriaFactory{
   Pizza createPizza(Ingredients ingredients);
   Ingredients createIngredients();
}

class ItalianPizzeriaFactory{
   Pizza createPizza(Ingredients ingredients){
     return new ItalianPizza(ingredients)
   }
   Ingredients createIngredients(){
     return new ItalianIngredients(SHEESE, TOMATO, SALADE)
   }
}
```